# How to display server name in psql prompt

Tags: psql

I have two servers running same PostgreSQL databases where one is production and one is development snapshot. It would be very handy for me if I could show the server name in the psql prompt (like this):

```
database_name@server_name >
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Edit**

edem's answer guided me into the right direction - setting the `PROMPT1` variable in `~/.psqlrc`. The only problem was that I was connecting to the database via Unix domain socket, so it printed `local` instead of server name.

I've used [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING) and [this](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Server-name-in-psql-prompt-td1857954.html) forum post, combined them and got this as a content of `.psqlrc` file:

```
 \set PROMPT1 '%/@%`hostname`:%>%R%#%x%x%x '
```

and now my prompt looks like:

```
database_name@my_database_server.com:5455=#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your $HOME directory make the file `.psqlrc` with this: `\set PROMPT1 '%/@%M %# '`

Then go into to psql and you will see something like this: `username@[local] >`